# Graphs of powers of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I was reading my textbook and I came across this proof for why an increase in the index $n$ for the function $f(x)=x^n$ makes the graph stay closer to the $x$-axis between $x=0$ and $x=1$ but then climbs more steeply beyond $x=1$.

It states in the proof that $x^{n+1}=x\cdot x^n$. Hence:

- $x^{n+1}>x^n$ when $0<x<1$ and $x^{n+1}>x^n$ when $x>1$

But why is this the case? I can't seem to quite understand the intuition behind it.

Comment: Think of multiplying 0.5 by 0.5. It represents HALF of 0.5, which is less than 0.5 itself. Then multiply 2 by 2. This represents DOUBLING of 2, which is greater than 2 itself.

Comment: What does it mean to multiply something at all? This is a very basic instance of proportionality: making a thing bigger makes it... bigger, making a thing smaller makes it... smaller.

Comment: If $s > 0$ and $0 < r < 1$ then $r \times s < 1 \times s.$  Alternatively, if $s > 0$ and $1 < r$, then $r \times s > 1 \times s.$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick proof:

Let $0 < x < 1$, and $y > 0$. Let's choose $\Delta x$ such that $x + \Delta x = 1$, and it isn't too hard to show that $0 < \Delta x < 1$. Now:

- $y$ and $\Delta x$ are both positive, so $y \Delta x$ is positive.
- $xy = (1 - \Delta x) y = y - y \Delta x$, but since $y \Delta x$ is positive we're subtracting a positive value, meaning $xy < y$.

For example, if $x = 0.7$, then $\Delta x = 0.3$, and $0.7 y = y - 0.3 y < y$.